# Closedness of bi-invariant differential form

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, differential-forms

I'm reading <Differential Geometry, Lie groups and Symmetric Spaces> by Helgason.

In Section 7 of Chapter 2, there is a lemma which says that the bi-invariant forms on a Lie group are closed.  [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1963895/proving-that-bi-invariant-forms-are-closed) gives one way to prove it, and I also know the proof using the inversion map. However, the author go through with somewhat unclear method to me. He says:

$(\tilde{X}_i^{R(\exp tX)})_e = Ad(\exp (-tX))(X_i)$ for $X \in \mathfrak{g}$, and

$\sum_1^p \omega(\tilde{X}_1, \dots, [\tilde{X}, \tilde{X}_i], \tilde{X}_{i+1}, \dots, \tilde{X}_p) = 0$ by the derivative of $Ad$ and the right-invariance of $\omega$,

(Here, $\omega$ is a bi-invariant $p$-form and $\tilde{X}_i$ is a left-invariant vector field corresponding to the tangent vector $X_i \in T_e G$.)

and then using the exterior derivative formula for $d \omega$, he conclude that $d \omega = 0$. I can understand all the process, but above two formulae. How can I obtain them? Maybe they can be easily derived by definition of $Ad$ and the right-invariance, but I can't find a way now. Any help will be appreciated so much.

Comment: Lee's introduction to smooth manifolds, chapter 14 has them. Alternatively, see chevalley and eilenberg's paper cohomology theory of lie groups and lie algebras, theorem 11.1 on page 101.

Comment: Link to Chevalley–Eilenberg, Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 63 (1948), 85-124: https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9947-1948-0024908-8